# RSA неверно расшифровывает при больших числах biginteger (c#)

Tags: c#, rsa, biginteger

Алгоритм рассчитан на шифрование чисел biginteger. Суть проблемы в том, что мой алгоритм работает только при длине ключа 16 бит, если поставить любое другое число, что всегда он работает неверно. Алгоритм создан на основе статьи из Википедии. Использовать встроенный в C# алгоритм RSACryptoServiceProvider я не могу.

```
public class RSA_I
{
    public BigInteger e;
    public BigInteger d;
    public BigInteger n;
    public BigInteger Fi;
    public RSA_I()
    {

    }
    public RSA_I(int keySize)
    {
        e = 65537;
        snova:
        BigInteger q = GetBigint(keySize / 2);
        BigInteger p = GetBigint(keySize / 2);
        if (p % 2 == 0) p += 1;
        if (q % 2 == 0) q += 1;
        while (!Test_MIl_Rab(q, keySize / 2, 5))
        {
            q = (q + GetBigint(keySize / 2)) / 2;
        }
        while (!Test_MIl_Rab(p, keySize / 2 , 5) && p == q)
        {
            p = (p + GetBigint(keySize / 2)) / 2;
        }
        BigInteger E_fynk = BigInteger.Multiply((q - 1) , (p - 1));
        if (E_fynk % e == 0) goto snova;
        Fi = E_fynk;
        n = BigInteger.Multiply(q, p);
        d = ObrEllement(e, E_fynk);
        if (BigInteger.ModPow(BigInteger.Multiply(d, e), 1, E_fynk) != 1) goto snova;
    }
    /// <summary>
    ///  шифрование
    /// </summary>
    public BigInteger Encrypt(BigInteger text)
    {
        return BigInteger.ModPow(text, e, n);
    }
    /// <summary>
    ///  дешифровка
    /// </summary>
    public BigInteger Decrypt(BigInteger text)
    {
        return BigInteger.ModPow(text, d, n);
    }
    public BigInteger GetBigint(int size)
    {
        var rand = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] By = new byte[size / 8];
        rand.GetBytes(By);
        BigInteger X = new BigInteger(By);
        return BigInteger.Abs(X);
    }
    private BigInteger GetBigint(BigInteger min, BigInteger max, int a)
    {
        RNGCryptoServiceProvider c = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] randomNumber = new byte[a / 8];
        c.GetBytes(randomNumber);
        BigInteger result = Math.Abs(BitConverter.ToInt32(randomNumber, 0));
        return (result % max + min) % max;
    }
    private bool Test_MIl_Rab(BigInteger n, int size_s, int Rt)
    {
        if (n <= 1) return false;
        if (n == 2) return true;
        if (n % 2 == 0) return false;
        BigInteger s = 0;
        BigInteger d = n - 1;
        while (d % 2 == 0)
        {
            d /= 2;
            s++;
        }

        long[] V = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
        for (int i = 0; i < Rt; i++)
        {
            BigInteger K = BigInteger.ModPow(V[i], d, n);
            for (int j = 0; j < s; j++)
            {
                K = (K * K) % n;
                if (K == n - 1 || K == -1) break;
            }
            if (K != n - 1) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    private BigInteger ObrEllement(BigInteger a, BigInteger mod)
    {
        BigInteger i = mod, v = 0, d = 1;
        while (a > 0)
        {
            BigInteger t = i / a, x = a;
            a = i % x;
            i = x;
            x = d;
            d = v - t * x;
            v = x;
        }
        v %= mod;
        if (v < 0) v = (v + mod) % mod;
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: а вы понимаете, что длинна модуля и длинна текста связаны?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman да, конечно, я знаю что модуль должен быть больше. Все условия я соблюдаю, но но алгоритм не работает... Например, при длине ключа 1024 бит я использую текст 240 бит ( например) и он неверно работает.

Comment: вот эта строчка `BigInteger.ModPow(BigInteger.Multiply(d, e), 1, E_fynk)` выглядит странно. зачем возводить в степень 1? думаю, что у вас ошибка в генерации значений `e` и `d`.